# How to sum all the numbers from a text file line by line in Python 3 and store into different file

Tags: python-3.x

Friends, can you helps me out to solve this python code.
I have to calculate the sum of all the numbers from two "txt" file line by line in Python-3 and store into a different file.
I have two "txt" file with different numbers that I have to calculate in Sum.

frist.txt= 
10 20 30
           40 50 60
           50 30 40

second.txt= 
10, 20, 30
            50, 40, 50
            80, 40, 20

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum numbers from a text file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924474/how-to-sum-numbers-from-a-text-file-in-python)

Comment: You'll need the builtin function `open('file path')`, to iterate on it line by line `for line in open('file path'):` and to split the string `line.split()` and cast it to numbers `(int(d) for d in line.split())`. The rest is basic python operations and variables, you can do it.

Comment: This is jus homework.

Comment: To Casting a number like in this case int(d) or float(d)  work same ? when we should use "int" or "float" for casting a number?

Answer (score 0):

the following code should solve your problem. I assumed that in your example your output file will be as follows:

```
output.txt =
120
290
260
```

Please also consider that I assumed your input files are comma separated values (as in your second.txt file).

```
total     = 0
totalLine = 0
firstSum  = []
secondSum = []

with open('first.txt', 'r') as first, open('second.txt', 'r') as second, open('output.txt', 'w') as outp:
  for line in first:
    try:
      firstList = line.split(" ")
      for number in firstList:
        totalLine += float(number)

      firstSum.append(totalLine)
      totalLine = 0
    except ValueError:
      print('{} is not a number in first file: use comma separated values!'.format(line))

  totalLine = 0

  for line in second:
    try:
      secondList = line.split(",")
      for number in secondList:
        totalLine += float(number)

      secondSum.append(totalLine)
      totalLine = 0
    except ValueError:
      print('{} is not a number in second file: use comma separated values!'.format(line))

  for idx in range(max(len(firstSum), len(secondSum))):
    if idx < len(firstSum) and idx < len(secondSum):
      total = firstSum[idx] + secondSum[idx]
    elif idx < len(firstSum):
      total = firstSum[idx]
    elif idx < len(secondSum):
      total = secondSum[idx]

    outp.write(str(total)+'\n')
    total = 0

print('Done!')
```

Comment: Man, don't do his homework, he'll miss an opportunity to learn.

Comment: Thanks Tantrixrobotboy for this nice help. It's really means a lot me to, as I am very new to Python. Just little correction. The 1st input "txt"  file has no comma, it's separated by white space, 2nd input "txt" file has comma. is there any change need to be done for 1st "txt" file access ?

Comment: Yes, just check the code above and it will work accordingly.

Comment: Thanks brother Tantrixrobotboy, I have two questions, could you answer me if you have time avaiable:

Comment: Thanks brother Tantrixrobotboy, I have two questions, could you answer me if you have time available: Q1: To Casting a number like in this case int(number) or float(number) work same ? when we should use "int" or "float" for casting a number? Like you casting here with Float. Is both I mean "INT" and "FLOAT" work same for casting a Number?  Q2: I saw few other Codes in file handling problems like this, some of them used "Strip" function after using  "Split"  function. Should we use "Strip" function with "Split" function? I run your code it's run fine without calling "Strip" function.

Comment: @sudeepbasak, for casting, it depends of what kind of data you are working with. If it's and integer, you will cast to Int, otherwise you will use other kind of casting (Float, for floating point numbers). Trimming the end of string is useless here (with strip), so you can just use split.